# Cannot create procedure in pl/pgsql but code works without create procedure

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have been trying to create a procedure in order to "`EXECUTE` `INSERT INTO`" a table.  I gave up on this and continued trying to dynamically generate the required insert into code.

I have solved my issue by not creating the procedure and simply starting from the "`DECLARE`" bit; but still have not managed to make the pl/pgsql procedure to work.

The following procedure is not working:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE populate_xcc_allocatable() AS
    $body$
        DECLARE 
            TYPE tablearray IS VARRAY(17) OF VARCHAR2(30);
            xa_tables tablearray := tablearray('allocation', 'container', 'location', 'sap_posting', 'status');
            total integer;
        BEGIN
            total := xa_tables.count;
            FOR i IN 1..total
                LOOP
                    dbms_output.put_line('INSERT INTO allocatable VALUES (nextval(''allocatable_id_seq''), ''' || xa_tables(i) || ''');');
                END LOOP;
        END;
    $body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


LINE 4:  TYPE tablearray IS VARRAY(17) OF VARCHAR2(30);
CONTEXT: invalid type name "tablearray IS VARRAY(17) OF VARCHAR2(30)"
```

But this is working fine:

```
DECLARE 
    TYPE tablearray IS VARRAY(17) OF VARCHAR2(30);
    xa_tables tablearray := tablearray('allocation', 'container', 'location', 'spirit_portion', 'activity', 'asset_ownership', 'container_location', 'sap_posting', 'status');
        total integer;
    BEGIN
        total := xa_tables.count;
        FOR i IN 1..total
            LOOP
                dbms_output.put_line('INSERT INTO xcc_allocatable VALUES (nextval(''xcc_allocatable_id_seq''), ''' || xa_tables(i) || ''');');
            END LOOP;
    END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL have not procedures but functions returns `void` instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION populate_xcc_allocatable() RETURNS void AS $body$
```

There is no 'local types', use [array type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) instead:

```
DECLARE
  xa_tables text[] := array[
    'allocation', 'container', 'location',
    'spirit_portion', 'activity', 'asset_ownership',
    'container_location', 'sap_posting', 'status'];
  total integer;
  i integer; -- Loop variables should be explicitly declared
```

To get array measurements use [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
BEGIN
  total := array_length(xa_tables, 1);
  FOR i in 1 .. total LOOP
    raise info 'INSERT INTO allocatable VALUES (nextval(''allocatable_id_seq''), ''%'');', xa_tables[i];
  END LOOP;
```

Any function should be finished by the `RETURN`:

```
  RETURN;
END $body$ language plpgsql;
```

Finally, the function you are trying to create can be replaced by the pure SQL:

```
INSERT INTO allocatable
  SELECT nextval('allocatable_id_seq'), x
  FROM unnest(array[
    'allocation', 'container', 'location',
    'spirit_portion', 'activity', 'asset_ownership',
    'container_location', 'sap_posting', 'status']) as t(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

`dbms_output.put_line` is oracle. and `declare` is oracle `anonymous PL/SQL block`

for postgres you should use `raise info '%','some text';` instead of `dbms_output.put_line('some text');`

and instead of anonymous PL/SQL block use `do` statement, like

```
do
$$
declare
begin
end;
$$
;
```

to be frank, I think you get more help if you change tag `postgres` to `oracle` and `plpgsql` to `plsql`...